How to pass a delegate to a component?
I'm trying to make an input box with drop down form control.  When the user types 3 or more characters I want to make an api call with the current input value, get an array of strings that contain the current value, and then present a dropdown box.
I've got most of that functionality down, but I'm trying to make the component as generic as possible so that it can be reused.  Ideally I don't want to component knowing where it's getting the searched term from, so I planned to have the parent pass in a delegate to handle that.  So far I have this:
@Component({
    selector: 'search-dropdown',
    templateUrl: './search-dropdown.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./search-dropdown.component.scss'],
    providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi:true,
      useExisting: SearchDropdownComponent
    }
  ]
})
export class SearchDropdownComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() loadValues!: (searchTerm: string) => Observable<string[]>;

  onInputChange(e: any) {
    const val = e.target.value;
    this.loadValues(val).subscribe( ... logic for dropdown here ... )
  }

  ... Implementation for ControlValueAccessor here ...
}

And I use this in the parent component like this:
<form [formGroup]="pRefGroup">
    ...
    <search-dropdown
        formControlName="referenceType"
        [loadValues]="loadReferenceTypes"
    />
    ...
</form>

Where loadReferenceTypes is a function on the host component that matches (searchTerm: string) => Observable<string[]>
When I do this I'm getting the error Can't bind to 'loadValues' since it isn't a known property of 'search-dropdown'.  I'm trying to find solutions for how delegates work in Angular but I'm not finding much that matches what I'm expecting, am I going in totally the wrong direction with this?

remove the "get", you can pass a function equal than a variable or an object: @Input() loadValues!:(searchTerm: string) => Observable<string[]>

Ah sorry that was a mistype, it wasn’t supposed to have get in there, that was something I tried after it wasn’t working.  I get the same result without get

it's looks like work, see a little stackblitz

Remove the "get", you can pass a function equal than a variable or an object:
@Input() loadValues!:(searchTerm: string) => Observable<string[]>

and use this.loadValues
  onInputChange(e: any) {
    const val = e.target.value;
    this.loadValues(val).subscribe( ... logic for dropdown here ... )
  }

BTW, better use (input) in your .html -the argument in this case is the own value, not the event- instead of (change)
  <input (input)="onInputChange($event)"..>

  onInputChange(value: any) {
    ....
  }

